# Error:26 Cannot connect to SQL 2008 database instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, sharepoint-2010, iis-6, connection-string

I have a sharepoint server on the DMZ and a SQL2008 server in the local domain. 
When I try to get the list of .NETUsers for the Central Administration site from IIS (version 7.5) i get thrown error:26! I have tried all possible combinations in specifying the connection string. 
I have also followed all directions on these links to resolve the isssue but it continues to persist.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx
AND
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from the Error itself, it turned out be a quite a complicated issue that ended up being resolved after a few days on the phone with Microsoft. The error read "The RPC service is Unavailable". There were issues with the way NetBios and DNS was qualifying the site and server names.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could you check the versions in your question. IIS 6 runs on Windows 2003, but it is not possible to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 2003.

This is a connection error, there are 2 possibilities:

- The call from the SharePoint server is blocked before it arrives at the database
- The call is being refused when it arrives at the database

You should start by making a drawing of the route between the Sp server and the database server. make sure to include all firewalls.

Then check the logs to see how far the call got.

You could also try monitoring the network traffic with wireshark to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: I have sharepoint installed on Windows 2008 server and the IIS version is 6.1. As mentioned before I am able to connect to the database using SSMS on the sharepoint server using the same connection string. I can ping and retrieve the instances from command line as well.

Comment: The version of IIS that runs on Windows 2008 is 7.0

Comment: I am sorry, the IIS manager version is 6.1. The IIS itself is version 7.5.7600.16385